# Get access token from Microsoft Graph PHP SDK v2

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-sdks

I followed the [readme](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php#call-microsoft-graph-using-the-v10-endpoint-and-models):

```php
$tokenRequestContext = new AuthorizationCodeContext(
    'tenantId',
    'clientId',
    'clientSecret',
    'authCode',
    'redirectUri'
);
$authProvider = new GraphPhpLeagueAuthenticationProvider($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);
$requestAdapter = new GraphRequestAdapter($authProvider);
$graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes, requestAdapter: $requestAdapter);
$user = $graphServiceClient->me()->get()->wait();
```

I'd like to get `AccessToken` which is used for the connection.

Comment: Why do you need the access token? One benefit of using a ready-made library like this is to avoid the need to worry about such details. The library automatically handles getting the token and then using it when it's needed for any subsequent actions.

Comment: @ADyson I need it for backward compatibility.

Comment: You mean you have some parts of the code where you are still making your own http requests? I see. I'd guess if it's anywhere it might be held in $authProvider . Have you checked documentation or source code of the library to see if it's mentioned?

Comment: @ADyson I haven't found anything about getting `AccessToken` in documentation, but I've found method `Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\PhpLeagueAccessTokenProvider::getAuthorizationTokenAsync` which is used during authenticatation and this method tries to save token (`Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\Oauth\DelegatedPermissionTrait::setCacheKey`) but only if it is JWT.

Comment: @ADyson has mentioned, I suggest you explain why you need to have the access token from the SDK. There is probably a better way to achieve your requirement without handling the access token yourself.